# My webservice wont work because HttpContentHeaders does not implement Add(System.Object)

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I'm new to this one so please be gentle.

I am adding a method to a webservice so that it can recieve POSTs from another.
The POST contains a JSON object in the body with parameters I need in the receiving solution.

I am using HttpClient's PostAsync method to send the data (as FormUrlEncodedContent) and I'm trying to recieve it as HttpRequestMessage.

When i try to compile and build I get this error in my recieving service

> To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have
>   an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their
>   inheritance hierarchy. System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders does
>   not implement Add(System.Object).

The odd thing is that I use these both of these in the POSTing webservice (I use ajax on a page to test it) and don't get this problem.

This is the sender:

```
string url = *url*;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
Dictionary<string, string> parameters;

parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{            
     { "*variablename1", *string* },               
     { "variablename2", *string* },
     { "variablename3", *string* },
     { "variablename4", *string* }
};     

     var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

     HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
```

And this is what is supposed to be receiving it...

```
public void Receive(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string data = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    *Database object* = new *Database object*();

    string decodedString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data);

    *Stuff that processes decodedString into a dictionary and puts it in database*
```

What I'd like is to know how I can get this to work, so an alternative to HttpRequestMessage that doesn't depend on HttpContentheaders having an add method, or another way of sending the post that doesn't require them on the recieving end.

Apologies for vague bits of code, I've only been a programmer for three months and my company works with a lot of confidential data, I'm just covering my back.

Comment: Which code gives error? Your sender code works for me. The data are posted.

Comment: The receiving code gives the error.
It's part of an older system and the web service class in question extends System.Web.Services.WebService. It's too big a system to rewrite the webservice.

I've not come across this way of doing it, the code I wrote uses HttpRequestMessage to receive posts. 
As I mentioned I've been in this job three months, and I'm working on a pre-existing system some of which we don't have access to because it was written by a third party.